# Как получиnm Id элемента через Xpath

Tags: парсер, xpath

```
<div class="lower-controls">
<button class="any-button" id="12103726">
 button
</button>
</div>
```

Подскажите как мне получить номер id элемента - 12103726?

Comment: `div/button/@id`? Или в чём проблема?

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Для поиска по любым элементам с нужным id:

```
*[@id="12103726"]
```

Для поиска по конкретным элементам (пример `button`)

```
button[@id="12103726"]
```

Если такой элемент существует, XPath вернет его